# Solving the recurrence $a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

How do I solve this recurrence relation?

$a_n = 2a_{n-1} -a_{n-2} $, with initial conditions, $a_0 = 0 $ and $a_1 = 1$

I notice that this resembles Pell numbers, but have no experience in solving such recurrences

Comment: Do you know what is a characteristic equation for a linear requarence equation ?

Comment: $a_2 = 2*1-0 = 2$..  $a_3 = 2*2-1 = 3$.. $a_4 = 2*3 - 2 = 4$.. So the pattern seems to be $a_n = n$?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, I couldn't spot that pattern because of a calculation error.

Comment: I don't know about characteristic equation, I did a quick search and am guessing I will have to do something like: $r^n = 2r^{n-1} - r^{n-2}$, solving it I get a repeated root of r = 1

Comment: Yes, this is the method. You suppose to search for a solution of the kind $\left\{a_n\right\}=\left\{ r^n\right\}$ and plug this in the recurrence equation.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $a_n-a_{n-1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$. So let $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$. You have $b_n=b_1$ for every $n$. You can conclude.

Answer (score 2):

A few methods of solving linear recurrence relations are described [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving).  It turns out that the unique solution is $a_n = n$.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the [Z-Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Table_of_common_Z-transform_pairs) provides a general methodology for solving linear difference equations.  Here, we have the difference equation

$$a_n=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\,\,,a_0=0,\,a_1=1 \tag 1$$

The Z-Transform $A(z)$ of $a_n$ is

$$A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{-n}$$

Application of the Z-Transform to both sides of $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
A(Z)&=2z^{-1}A(z)+2a_{-1}-z^{-2}A(z)-z^{-1}a_{-1}-a_{-2}\\\\
&\implies A(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)^2} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

The inverse Z-Transform is given by

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_CA(z)z^{n-1}\,dz\tag 3
\end{align}$$

where $C$ is any contour that contains the unit disk.  Using $A(z)$ from $(2)$ in $(3)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_CA(z)z^{n-1}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{z^n}{(z-1)^2}\,dz\\\\
&=\text{Res}\left(\frac{z^n}{(z-1)^2},z=1\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{z\to 1}\frac{d}{dz}\left(z^n\right)\\\\
&=n
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{a_n=n}$$